# Crystal Reports; Last Accessed

Tags: crystal-reports

How do I determine when a crystal report was last run?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - you can't. Not unless the application used to load them is doing its own logging, anyway. But for a standalone Crystal Report there's no way of knowing when it was last run.